# How to map each type of properties in object to a property in interface?

Tags: typescript, typemaps

I am trying to create a dispatch action interface for a react-redux project in typescript. I would like to be able to decide type property in action interface based on another object which has all types that can be dispatched.

input:

```
const FooActions = {
    REMOVE_FOO: "removeFOO",
    ADD_FOO: "addFOO",
    UPDATE_FOO: "updateFOO",
};

interface FooActionType {
    type: "MAP ALL property values from FooActions";
    payload: any;
}
```

expected output:

```
interface FooActionType {
    type: "removeFOO" | "addFOO" | "updateFOO";
    payload: any;
}
```

Comment: You just want to go from `FooActions ` to `FooActionType ` ?

Comment: no...i want FooActionType.type to be one of FooActions values. That would be ["removeFOO" | "addFOO" | "updateFOO"].

Comment: why don't you just declare approp. `type FooActions = 'action a' | 'action b'` and then stick to it? Bypassing more verbose `const FooActions = { ... }`?

Comment: I don't want to declare approp because I want to be able to import that const FooActions and use it to dispatch actions from other places.

Answer (score 1):

To get the types of a the values in an object you can use `T[keyof T]` (with `T` being the type). To preserve string literal types in `FooActions` you will need to use a type assertion.

Given the above it is simple to create `FooActionType`:

```
const FooActions = {
    REMOVE_FOO: "removeFOO",
    ADD_FOO: "addFOO",
    UPDATE_FOO: "updateFOO",
} as const;

interface FooActionType {
    type: typeof FooActions[keyof typeof FooActions];
    payload: any;
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYiEBBYUCW4IwLwwN4BQMxMASgKICyA8gGrkD6c11AXDAEQBOApgLYgAbj2bUOAGiIkkAERlMW7DgEMAJqtESpxAKoAFGUgAqjUUoCuAB1XKoIlloC+MZVlCQoAbgIE0YO1wAZsrAPPCIKOjgRgCelmGEJDBQcTzsKfEggeHIqBiQANoA1jwxWcmp5Qi5UZAAut5JlsoxADYgauzKYDHejkA)

Comment: using this method, I am able to assign type with any string value. I would like to be able to assign only one of three values from FooActions to type. in the sense only "removeFOO" | "addFOO" | "updateFOO", these values shoudl be allowed to be assigned to type.